# Are there any LDAP search queries which could be used in a way akin to malicious SQL Injection?

Tags: c#, security, active-directory, sql-injection

I know the "search" query bit of what I have asked may preclude any crud operations on AD.  But opening up the question a bit. If on a website for example, I am taking input from a text box to search for users, I would hazard a guess that I am potentially leaving myself open to some kind of malicious activity, if I don't try and curtail it. What do I need to look out for?
For example, anyone who is a bit LDAP savvy might be able to enter a command which might cause a long running process taking up vital resources (consider someone with a bit of a grudge spinning up loads of requests with a really nutty search filter). Notwithstanding my ability to limit to a prescribed OU,  limiting the scope a little I'm sure there is still loopholes here, potentially?

Comment: Injection weaknesses can occur in any system where data can be misinterpreted as commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like any application interface that accepts user input, there's a potential for an attacker to supply malicious inputs that the application may not expect. It is always best to perform strong white-list validation to ensure user input matches known/expected values. There are other cases where a more robust defense may be required.

If you are taking user input, and putting directly into an LDAP query, you'll want to defend against inclusion of unforeseen LDAP meta-characters. If an attacker is successful in modifying LDAP statements, it is a vulnerability known as LDAP Injection.

The following articles do a good job explaining what is LDAP Injection, and how you can defend against it:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/LDAP_injection
http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246947/LDAP%20Injection

Keep in mind user input can be ANYTHING from the client side, not just application POST/GET parameters. Things like HTTP (or other protocol)headers, are just as vulnerable. If an attacker is able to intercept the data before it is transmitted to the application, then it should be considered "tainted" and proper defenses should be applied to make sure it does not contain malicious input.